# Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') in django and next js

Tags: django, next.js, django-staticfiles

hello i did everything with integration but nothing seems working,its again saying the same error

all next js files are default no changes

[image]

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/.next/static/css')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('',views.test)

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                           document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
     urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                            document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

pls help me find a solution to this problem i have done everything that i can do with this integration

Comment: You may have a URL routing issue. Please share the urlpatterns in your urls.py.

Comment: this is because of it takes your style sheet type as `(text/html)`  try to  include type whenever you add style sheet for example `<style type="text/css"> `

Comment: edited.. pls look in to it

Comment: You must serve  static assets from the public folder in next js. have you done so? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving